# can't Ordinal Encode my data using fit_transform of category_encoders

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, categorical-data, ordinal

I'm trying to fit_transform the `OrdinalEncoder` of `category_encoders` to one of the columns of my [data](https://www.kaggle.com/stevezhenghp/airbnb-price-prediction).
what I've tried seeing [documentation](http://contrib.scikit-learn.org/categorical-encoding/ordinal.html) is:

```
    import category_encoders as ce

    # here i'm defining mapping for OrdinalEncoder
    property_ordinal_mapping_1 = [{"col":"property_type", "mapping": [('Apartment', 1),('House', 2),('Condominium', 3),
                                                                      ('Townhouse', 4),('Loft', 5),('Other', 6),
                                                                      ('Guesthouse', 7),('Bed & Breakfast', 8),
                                                                      ('Bungalow', 9),('Villa', 10),('Dorm', 11),
                                                                      ('Guest suite', 12),('Camper/RV', 13),
                                                                      ('Timeshare', 14),('Cabin', 15),('In-law', 16),
                                                                      ('Hostel', 17),('Boutique hotel', 18),('Boat', 19),
                                                                      ('Serviced apartment', 20),('Tent', 21),('Castle', 22),
                                                                      ('Vacation home', 23),('Yurt', 24),('Hut', 25),
                                                                      ('Treehouse', 26),('Chalet', 27),('Earth House', 28),
                                                                      ('Tipi', 29),('Train', 30),('Cave', 31),
                                                                      ('Casa particular', 32),('Parking Space', 33),
                                                                      ('Lighthouse', 34),('Island', 35)
                                                                     ]
                                },
                               ]
    # preparing the OrdinalEncoder for fitting and transforming
    property_encoder_1 = ce.OrdinalEncoder(mapping = property_ordinal_mapping_1, return_df = True, cols=["property_type"])
```

the problem that arises when I try to `fit_transfom` is:
`df_train = property_encoder_1.fit_transform(air_cat_2)`
the error:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-96-9cea1713182c> in <module>()
----> 1 df_train = property_encoder_1.fit_transform(air_cat_2)
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/sklearn/base.py in fit_transform(self, X, y, **fit_params)
    551         if y is None:
    552             # fit method of arity 1 (unsupervised transformation)
--> 553             return self.fit(X, **fit_params).transform(X)
    554         else:
    555             # fit method of arity 2 (supervised transformation)

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/category_encoders/ordinal.py in fit(self, X, y, **kwargs)
    139             cols=self.cols,
    140             handle_unknown=self.handle_unknown,
--> 141             handle_missing=self.handle_missing
    142         )
    143         self.mapping = categories

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/category_encoders/ordinal.py in ordinal_encoding(X_in, mapping, cols, handle_unknown, handle_missing)
    288             for switch in mapping:
    289                 column = switch.get('col')
--> 290                 X[column] = X[column].map(switch['mapping'])
    291 
    292                 try:

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pandas/core/series.py in map(self, arg, na_action)
   3380         """
   3381         new_values = super(Series, self)._map_values(
-> 3382             arg, na_action=na_action)
   3383         return self._constructor(new_values,
   3384                                  index=self.index).__finalize__(self)

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pandas/core/base.py in _map_values(self, mapper, na_action)
   1216 
   1217         # mapper is a function
-> 1218         new_values = map_f(values, mapper)
   1219 
   1220         return new_values

pandas/_libs/lib.pyx in pandas._libs.lib.map_infer()

TypeError: 'list' object is not callable
```

`sklearn.preprocessing.OrdinalEncoder` had similar error.
what I'm doing wrong and how do I solve this. I've double checked the class names of my column and rewrote the whole code and nothing seemed to help; Or is there any alternate way that I can do this.
Please don't mark my question as duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

The documentation is incorrect. The syntax for `mapping` is now different. See here: https://github.com/scikit-learn-contrib/categorical-encoding/issues/193

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to use `OrdinalEncoder` from `sklearn.preprocessing`. I've had same problem when doing`fit_transform` of `OrdinalEncoder` too. So, [this post](https://github.com/ageron/handson-ml/issues/348#issuecomment-455482303) cleared all my thoughts.

**EDIT 1:**
Here's what I've done(I preserved it for re-use):

```
def ordinal_encode(a_column_of_dataframe):

    # make an array of unique categories by count for preference, because apparently the most occurred is what most offered(in context of hotel rooms)
    from collections import Counter
    most_occurred_desc = np.array(sorted(a_column_of_dataframe.values, key=Counter(a_column_of_dataframe.values).get, reverse=True))
    unique_elements = list(Counter(most_occured_desc).keys())

    # make an ordinal encoder with that ordered list
    from sklearn.preprocessing import OrdinalEncoder
    prop_ord_enc = OrdinalEncoder(categories=[unique_elements])

    # since transform needs list of lists 
    list_of_lists = [[i] for i in list(a_column_of_dataframe) ]

    # transform it now(ordinal encode it), which will return list of lists, just as been passed
    encoded_props = prop_ord_enc.fit_transform(list_of_lists)

    # return the flattened array
    return np.asarray(encoded_props).flattened()
```